# use single unique client for multiple realm in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, multi-tenant

We are using keycloak in a multi-tenant micro-services application. 
We have planed to use one `realm` *per* tenant. 
Also there is single endpoint that all user requests (from all tenants) authenticated with JWT bearer token flow. 
Is that possible to create one application client in keycloak and share it amount all realms?
Or we have to create a client (with same name) for each realms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that possible to create one application client in keycloak and
> share it amount all realms?

Out-of-the box this is not possible, just like users, clients are defined at the Realm level, and consequently, cannot be shared among realms.

Comment: It is really a dream crash, to not have this feature.

Comment: ahah nice one :D